# Algorithm for "Circus tower"

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

Here is the problem from the "Cracking the coding interview" book:

A circus is designing a tower routine consisting of people standing atop one another’s 
shoulders. For practical and aesthetic reasons, each person must be both shorter and lighter than the person below him or her. Given the heights and weights of each person in the circus, write a method to compute the largest possible number of people 
in such a tower.

EXAMPLE:

Input:

```
(ht, wt): (65, 100) (70, 150) (56, 90) (75, 190) (60, 95) (68, 110)
```

Output:

The longest tower is length 6 and includes from top to bottom:

```
(56, 90) (60,95) (65,100) (68,110) (70,150) (75,190)
```

Here is the solution from the book:

"When we cut out all the fluff to this problem, we can understand that the problem is really the following.

We have a list of pairs of items. Find the longest sequence such that both the first and second items are in non-decreasing order."

I came up with this example:

```
      {1,1} 
   {3,3} {7,2}
{6,4} {9,9} {8,5}
```

Here, values of the sequence are not in a non-decreasing order, but still it's a valid tower. And I cannot find a way to organize the same items into another tower that would have items in non-decreasing order. I believe there is no such way. So it appears to me that the solution is incorrect.

Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The values are not in non-decreasing order => it's not a valid tower - by definition, according to the problem text. What makes you say it is valid?

Comment: In {3,3} -> {7,2}, 2<3, therefore it is not a valid tower.

Comment: @Blorgbeard {1,1} sits on top of {3,3} and {7,2}; {3,3} sits on top of {6,4} and {9,9} and {7,2} sits on top of {9,9} and {8,5}.

Comment: @Blorgbeard never mind, I see now that problem never said that there is two people standing below each person :) I knew I was missing something. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

No, Your values are not in non decreasing order. As @MooseBoys comment says weight of the 3rd value in greater than 2nd in your case. ({3,3} -> {7,2}, 2<3)

The problem is a slight variation of Longest Increasing subsequence(LIS) (DP).

You can sort the elements with respect to height, And then apply find the longest Increasing subsequence on weight.

Please find the java implementation below:

```
class Person implements Comparable<Person> {
    int height;
    int weight;

    public Person(int height, int weight) {
        this.height = height;
        this.weight = weight;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Person{" +
                "height=" + height +
                ", weight=" + weight +
                '}';
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Person p) {
        if(this.height>p.height) {
            return 1;
        } else if(this.height < p.height) {
            return -1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}

public class CircusTower {

    public void calculatePeople(Person[] input) {

        int weightArray[] = new int[input.length];
        String[] output = new String[input.length];
        for (int i=0;i<input.length;i++) {
            weightArray[i] = 1;
            output[i] = input[i].toString() + "";
        }
        int maxLength = 0;

        for (int i=1;i<input.length;i++) {
            for (int j=0;j<i;j++) {
                if( weightArray[j]+1>weightArray[i] && input[i].weight>input[j].weight) {
                    weightArray[i] = weightArray[j] + 1;
                    output[i] = output[j] + " " + input[i].toString();
                    if(maxLength<weightArray[i]) {
                        maxLength = weightArray[i];
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println();


        for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
            if (weightArray[i] == maxLength) {
                System.out.println("Longest Increasing subsequence - " + output[i] + " of length = " + maxLength);
            }
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CircusTower ct = new CircusTower();
        Person p1 = new Person(65,100);
        Person p2 = new Person(70,150);
        Person p3 = new Person(56, 90);
        Person p4 = new Person(75, 190);
        Person p5 = new Person(60, 95);
        Person p6 = new Person(68, 110);

        Person[] array = new Person[]{p1,p2,p3,p4,p5,p6};

        Arrays.sort(array);

        ct.calculatePeople(array);

    }

}
```

I am using the **n square** implementation of LIS problem, U can also use the better one in **nlogn**.

Hope it clarifies.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I edited my question so it would be clearer how the tower is built. {1,1} sits on top of {3,3} and {7,2}; {3,3} sits on top of {6,4} and {9,9} and {7,2} sits on top of {9,9} and {8,5}

Comment: Never mind, I see now that problem never said that there is two people standing below each person :) I knew I was missing something. Thanks!